# How to remove a mongo collection name with a special character �?

Tags: mongodb, jruby

Accidentally created a collection with "�" in its name. Now i'm looking for a way to delete it.

P.s. I tried `db['�'].drop()` and that did not work out for me.

Comment: you have named collection just "?"

Comment: Thanks much. Just figured it out myself. Converting � to unicode solved the problem.

Comment: please post answer, so that it will help others

Comment: you can add it as an answer and accept your own answer that will be good (y) because that space is for question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself. `db['\ufffd'].drop()` worked for me. Converting "�" to unicode solved the problem. Hope someone finds it useful. This should work for other special characters as well.